# NodeJS child process: write to stdin arbitrary times

Tags: node.js, read-eval-print-loop, child-process

i'm trying to make and c REPL, so I need to interact with the stdin how many times as the c code needs. Currently a have this code (Just one time)

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const gcc = spawn('gcc', ['-Wall', 'main.c', '-o', 'main', '-lm']);

gcc.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

gcc.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

gcc.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
  const child = spawn('./main')
  child.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');
  child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
  child.stdin.write("5\n");
  child.stdin.end();
});
```

Any clues?

Comment: Why I'm getting downvoted? I don't understand :(

Comment: You are getting downvoted because this is a very vague question. You should show what it is supposed to do, what it currently does with as much detail as reasonable and what you have tried to get it to work.